# Batch File - Choice, indent prompt

Tags: batch-file

I am using choice in batch file to display a prompt like this..

```
:choice
set /P "c= Is this Correct? (Y/N)"
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :movespot
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :exitspot
goto :choice
```

It works correctly but it is ignoring the space in 'Is this Correct? (Y/N)' that I am trying to use to indent the echo.

Is there another way I can do this?

Comment: Yes.  `SET /P` will strip any leading spaces when executing.  There is a trick to have spaces at the beginning but requires you to capture a backspace into a variable first.  Then you can do something like this: `set /P "c=X%bs%        Is this Correct? (Y/N)"`

Comment: For me, this gives me the X before backspace

Comment: Did you find the code on how to set a backspace character to a variable?

Comment: Possible solution: try to [echo only white space and no newline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40943134), then do `set /P` in a second step...

Comment: ...or try `for /F %%B in ('prompt $H ^& for %%# in ^(.^) do rem/') do set "bs=%C"` to get a back-space character into variable `bs` ans retry Squashman's suggestion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a code solution to print spaces in your `SET /P` output.

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('"prompt $H&for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "BS=%%a"

set /P "c=X%BS%          Is there 10 spaces before? (Y/N)"
```

Answer (score 2):

For such Yes/No selection I recommend to use the [`choice` command](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html), because it does not accept entries other than `Y`/`N` (except for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>, but you can abort `set /P` with them too).

Nevertheless, `choice`, removes leading white-spaces, just like `set /P`; it even removes trailing ones. Though the [backspace-(<kbd>←</kbd>-)trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51181016) demonstrated by [Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694) also works here, for both sides:

```cmd
for /F %%C in ('prompt $H ^& for %%# in ^(.^) do rem/') do set "BS=%%C"
set /P C="_%BS% Is there a leading space and a (kept) trailing space? "
choice /M "_%BS% Is there a leading and two trailing spaces? _%BS%" /N
```

Note that `choice` always appends one <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to the prompt text, if any is specified (`/M`). So one of the aforementioned two trailing spaces is the additionally appended one. By default, `choice` appends the list of choices (`[Y,N]`) then, unless `/N` is given.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PowerShell with "Choice /M", then the following will work.

In Character Map (Win+R > charmap), on the first page, there is a no-break space.  This can be entered by press and holding the Alt key and typing 0160 on your number pad (Specifically, that keypad on the right).  PowerShell recognizes this as a character different from 'space' where CMD does not.

In the image, attached, you can see both lines look identical.  However, in the second line, I used Alt+0160 for the space instead.
[No-Break Space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtBJt.png)